# XSLT 2.0 to flatten and prune excessive <span>s

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

### Background

We're in charge of processing XML text generated by a different group in our company.  Some of this XML is created in Confluence (for those of you familiar with it), and some of it was originally authored in other tools (most commonly MS Word), and imported into Confluence.

The imported content looks fine on the screen, but it can be quite ugly under the hood.  To save our sanity, we do a good bit of XSLT-based preprocessing on the XML before running the files through the rest of our toolchain.

One challenge that is currently more complex than I can comfortably handle is excessive spans.  During the authoring process in MS Word, the document creators applied colors to different sections at different times.  MS Word dutifully maintained the history of these changes in the file's source, and never cleaned things up.  All that irrelevant history is present in the Confluence XML after importing, causing us some grief.

### The source

Here's a sample.  Text and URLs have been munged to protect the guilty.  :)

```
<p>
    <span style="color: rgb(51,51,51);">Mostly black text <span style="color: rgb(255,0,0);"><span style="color: rgb(51,51,51);">and more mostly black,</span> followed by red</span>. And this is mostly black again. And <a href="http://example.com/a_page">a link</a> for good measure.<br/></span>
</p>
```

We have two problems here.

1. Some spans set the color to black, or close enough to black: `color: rgb(51,51,51)` for instance is dark enough that we want to treat this as functionally equivalent to `color: rgb(0,0,0)`.  Since the default color of the entire page is black, this span is garbage if it appears as the outermost child of a structural element (such as `<p>`) that has no color defined.  We want to remove any such span with a value of `rgb(55,55,55)` or less.
2. Due to span nesting, there's an awful lot of redundancy.  We want to flatten this structure as much as we can, so `<span style="color...">` elements do not contain other `<span style=color...">` elements.  This may not always be possible, such as when a `<span style=color...">` element is a descendant of another `<span style=color...">` element, but is also a child of something else.

A bigger sample, with different scenarios:

```
<page>
    <p><span style="color: rgb(51,51,51);">Mostly black text <span style="color: rgb(255,0,0);"><span style="color: rgb(51,51,51);">and more mostly black,</span> followed by red</span>. And this is mostly black again. And <a href="http://example.com/a_page">a link</a> for good measure.<br/></span></p>
    <p><span style="color: rgb(255,0,0);"><span style="color: rgb(51,51,51);"><span style="color: rgb(255,0,0);"><span style="color: rgb(51,51,51);">This is black,</span> this is red</span>. This is black again.<br/></span></span></p>
    <p><span style="color: rgb(0,51,102);"><span style="color: rgb(0,51,102);">Dark blue text</span> with more dark blue after it.</span></p>
    <p><span style="color: rgb(0,51,102);"><span style="color: rgb(128,51,102);"><span style="color: rgb(128,51,102);"><span style="color: rgb(0,51,102);">Dark blue</span> and magenta text.</span></span></span></p>
    <p><span style="color: rgb(0,51,102);"><span style="color: rgb(128,51,102);"><span style="font-weight: bold;"><span style="color: rgb(0,51,102);">Dark blue</span> and bold magenta text.</span></span> More dark blue.</span></p>
    <p><span style="color: rgb(0,51,102);"><span style="color: rgb(128,51,102);"><span style="color: rgb(128,51,102);"><span style="color: rgb(0,51,102);">Dark blue</span> and magenta text.</span></span></span></p>
    <p>This is default text, <span style="color: rgb(255,0,0);">with some red <span style="color: rgb(51,51,51);"> and some more embedded "black", and <a href="http://www.example.com/eggplant">a link with <span style="color: rgb(0,0,0);">more inline color formatting</span> for good measure</a>.</span></span></p>
    <p><span style="color: rgb(0,51,102);"><span style="color: rgb(128,51,102);"><span style="color: rgb(128,51,102);">Magenta on the front. <span style="color: rgb(0,51,102);">Dark blue</span> and magenta text.</span></span></span></p>
    <p><span style="color: rgb(0,51,102);">Dark blue. <span style="color: rgb(128,51,102);">Magenta here. <span style="color: rgb(0,51,102);">Dark blue</span> and magenta text.</span></span></p>
</page>
```

### The target

What we want that turned into:

```
<page>
    <p>Mostly black text and more mostly black,<span style="color: rgb(255,0,0);"> followed by red</span>. And this is mostly black again. And <a href="http://example.com/a_page">a link</a> for good measure.<br/></p>
    <p>This is black,<span style="color: rgb(255,0,0);"> this is red</span>. This is black again.<br/></p>
    <p><span style="color: rgb(0,51,102);">Dark blue text with more dark blue after it.</span></p>
    <p><span style="color: rgb(0,51,102);">Dark blue</span><span style="color: rgb(128,51,102);"> and magenta text.</span></p>
    <p><span style="font-weight: bold;"><span style="color: rgb(0,51,102);">Dark blue</span><span style="color: rgb(128,51,102);"> and bold magenta text.</span></span><span style="color: rgb(0,51,102);"> More dark blue.</span></p>
    <p><span style="color: rgb(0,51,102);">Dark blue</span><span style="color: rgb(128,51,102);"> and magenta text.</span></p>
    <p>This is default text, <span style="color: rgb(255,0,0);">with some red </span> and some more embedded "black", and <a href="http://www.example.com/eggplant">a link with <span style="color: rgb(0,0,0);">more inline color formatting</span> for good measure</a>.</p>
    <p><span style="color: rgb(128,51,102);">Magenta on the front. </span><span style="color: rgb(0,51,102);">Dark blue</span><span style="color: rgb(128,51,102);"> and magenta text.</span></p>
    <p><span style="color: rgb(0,51,102);">Dark blue. </span><span style="color: rgb(128,51,102);">Magenta here. </span><span style="color: rgb(0,51,102);">Dark blue</span><span style="color: rgb(128,51,102);"> and magenta text.</span></p>
</page>
```

The depth of nested `<span>` tags appears to be quite arbitrary.  In one notable instance, we saw a tag structure 15 levels deep.  o.O

My approach so far, such as it is, is basically brute-forcing the problem by trying to come up with as many different scenarios as possible. I've learned over the years that brute-forcing is usually an indicator that I'm going in the wrong direction.

I've spent a couple of days chipping away at this, and since I can't come up with something that

1. covers all the bases and works consistently, and
2. is maintainable and at least halfway elegant,

I bring this here in the hopes of gleaning a nugget from someone else's greater wisdom.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is a two-pass transform. First, for each `p` element you could find all non-span elements, and create a sequence of new elements, which contain the relevant colour as an attribute

```
    <xsl:variable name="text">
        <xsl:for-each select=".//node()[not(self::span)]">
            <xsl:variable name="color" select="ancestor::span[contains(@style, 'color: ')][1]/@style" />
            <text color="{substring-before(substring-after($color, 'color: '), ';')}">
                <xsl:copy-of select="." />
            </text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
```

So, for example, for the first `p` element in your sample, this variable would contain this..

```
<text color="rgb(51,51,51)">Mostly black text </text>
<text color="rgb(51,51,51)">and more mostly black,</text>
<text color="rgb(255,0,0)"> followed by red</text>
<text color="rgb(51,51,51)">. And this is mostly black again. And </text>
<text color="rgb(51,51,51)"><a href="http://example.com/a_page">a link</a></text>
<text color="rgb(51,51,51)">a link</text>
<text color="rgb(51,51,51)"> for good measure.</text>
<text color="rgb(51,51,51)"><br></text>
```

You can then use `xsl:for-each-group` on this `$text` variable to group adjacent nodes with the same `color` attribute.

Try this approach

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="p">
        <xsl:variable name="text">
            <xsl:for-each select=".//node()[not(self::span)]">
                <xsl:variable name="color" select="ancestor::span[contains(@style, 'color: ')][1]/@style" />
                <text color="{substring-before(substring-after($color, 'color: '), ';')}">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
                </text>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$text" />
        <p>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="$text/text" group-adjacent="@color">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="@color = '' or @color='rgb(51,51,51)'">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()/node()" />
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <span style="color: {current-grouping-key()};">
                            <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()/node()" />
                        </span>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In fact, having written that, I realised you can actually do this in a single pass, without the need to create a variable first.

Try this too

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="p">
        <p>
            <xsl:for-each-group select=".//node()[not(self::span)]" 
                                group-adjacent="substring-before(substring-after(ancestor::span[contains(@style, 'color: ')][1]/@style, 'color: '), ';')">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key() = '' or current-grouping-key()='rgb(51,51,51)'">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()" />
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <span style="color: {current-grouping-key()};">
                            <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()/node()" />
                        </span>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Interesting approach, thank you! :) This has some shortcomings, however. 1) No evaluation of color values: we want to remove any `<span>` tag where all three RGB values are the same, and where those values are less than 55. 2) This is Confluence XML, where text may be contained in other structures. I used `<p>` for the example simply because that's what was in the files to hand; however, text may also be in something else, such as `<li>`, `<td>`, `<h2>`, `<ac:structured-macro>`, etc. That said, you've given me some good ideas - particularly, by not matching on `<span>` but something else. Ta!